3D Parabolic projectiles undershoot target in GDScript
I have this script on a cannon in my scene.
It is supposed to shoot a projectile in a parabolic trajectory to where the cursor is pointed at when clicked.
For whatever reason, the fired projectiles always undershoot the desired target. And it gets worse, the farther away the target is.
I found this code online and I have no Idea about the math behind it. It was originally written for Unity, I guess, but I changed it to use GDScript instead.
The canons global position is (-123.23, 0, 0) and even when I position it at (0, 0, 0) it's still undershooting.
extends Node3D

var gravity = -Vector3(0, 9.8, 0)
var shotSpeed = Data.shotSpeed
@onready var barrel = $Cylinder_001
@onready var bulletSpawn = $Cylinder_001/bulletSpawn
@onready var shotScene =  preload("res://Scenes/shot.tscn")

# Called when the node enters the scene tree for the first time.
func _ready():
    pass # Replace with function body.


# Called every frame. 'delta' is the elapsed time since the previous frame.
func _process(delta):
    var directionToCursor = position.direction_to(Data.playerCamera.get_mouse_position_on_ground())
    var rotationYtoCursor = Vector3(1,0,0).angle_to(directionToCursor)
    if directionToCursor.z >= 0:
        rotationYtoCursor = -rotationYtoCursor
    rotation.y = rotationYtoCursor
    if Input.is_action_just_pressed("Shoot"):
        shoot_at_target(Data.playerCamera.get_mouse_position_on_ground())

func shoot_at_target(targetPosition: Vector3):
    var shotInstance:RigidBody3D = shotScene.instantiate()
    get_parent().add_child(shotInstance)
    shotInstance.player = self
    shotInstance.position = bulletSpawn.global_position
    shotInstance.linear_velocity = get_shot_velocity(targetPosition)

func get_shot_velocity(targetPos: Vector3) -> Vector3:
    var toTarget = (targetPos - bulletSpawn.global_position)
    var gSquared = gravity.length_squared()
    var speed = Data.shotSpeed
    var b = speed * speed + gravity.dot(toTarget)
    var discriminant = b * b - gSquared * toTarget.length_squared()
    
    
    print("----------")
    print("StartPos: " + str(bulletSpawn.global_position))
    print("targetPos: " + str(targetPos))
    print("toTarget: " + str(toTarget))
    
    if discriminant < 0:
        return Vector3(0, 0, 0)
    
    var discRoot = sqrt(discriminant)
    
    var T = sqrt(sqrt(toTarget.length_squared() * 4 / gSquared))
    
    var velocity = toTarget / T - gravity * T / 2
    print("Velocity: " + str(Vector3(velocity.x, velocity.y, velocity.z)))
    print("----------")
    return Vector3(velocity.x, velocity.y, velocity.z)

Changing the line
var velocity = toTarget / T - gravity * T / 2
to
var velocity = toTarget * 1.34 / T - gravity * T / 2
actually gives me a rough estimate which makes the projectile hit much more accurately, but still over- or undershoots a little bit depending on the distance to the target.

How is targetPosition calculated? Do spawning position of bullet and target position have same or different Y values? Can you show a minimal example project?
